# Django runserver is not working with ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'test' error

Tags: python, django, docker

Getting the below error when I am running the `python app/manage.py runserver` command. Not sure what is going wrong there. I tried with different version of django and getting the same error with all django version.

- Python: 3.6.6
- Django: 3.1.5
- ubuntu: 14.04

I have 'test' in INSTALLED_APPS. when I remove that Django is running. Not sure what needs to be done in order to have 'test' in installed_apps.

**Error:**

```
root@e1dd33f6a3ef:/code# python app/manage.py runserver --noreload
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app/manage.py", line 13, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 357, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'test'
```

Comment: Have you created an app named 'test' on this project?

Comment: I have `test' in INSTALLED_APPS @Patrick Freitas

Comment: if I remove `test' in INSTALLED_APPS ending up with different issue. `Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/utils.py", line 66, in __getitem__
    return self._engines[alias]
KeyError: 'django'`

Comment: Keep 'test' on your INSTALLED_APPS and check if your virtual environment is activated before run this command

Comment: I have docker container wherein it has installed all requirements and also tried with venv . In both cases same error only

Comment: can u show us the tree of ur working directory ??